# What is the authenticity of the athar about Umar not doing Raf’ al-Yadayn in prayer?

Tags: hadith, salat, authenticity

> حدثنا يحيى بن آدم، عن حسن بن عياش، عن عبد الملك بن أبجر، عن الزبير بن عدي، عن إبراهيم، عن الأسود، قال: صليت مع عمر فلم يرفع يديه في شيء من صلاته إلا حين افتتح الصلاة
>
> Yahya bin Adam told us, on the authority of Hassan bin Ayyash, on the authority of Abdul Malik bin Abjar, on the authority of Zubair bin Adi, on the authority of Ibrahim, on the authority of Al-Aswad, he said:
>
> I prayed with Omar, and he did not raise his hands in any of his prayer except when he opened the prayer.
>
> [<s>2469</s> مصنف ابن ابی شیبہ الرقم](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33038/2734)

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam.  Strictly speaking this is not a hadith as it is rather describing what 'Umar did. And there are lots of narration supporting this too and this is the known choice of both Maliki and Hanafi madhhab. Even if imam Malik reported ahadith saying otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

It is an authentic narration.

Imām Abū Jaáfar al-Ţaĥāwī comments on this:

“This is Úmar, may Allāh be pleased with him, he would not raise his hands except in the first takbīr in this ĥadīth, and it is a şaĥīĥ ĥadīth.”

[Sharĥ Ma'áānī al-Āthār, 1/227]

[image]

Mullā Álī al-Qārī writes regarding it:

“Ţaĥāwī and then Bayhaqī narrated from the ĥadīth of Ĥasan ibn Áyyāsh, with a şaĥīĥ sanad from Aswad.”

[Mirqāt, 2/486]

[image]

Ibn al-Turkmānī writes:

“This sanad, too, is şaĥīĥ according to the conditions of Muslim.”

[Jawhar al-Naqī, 1/136]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This narration appears in a chapter of Musannaf (abu Bakr) ibn abi Shaybah in which he quoted those people of knowledge (sahabah and tabi'yn etc.) who used not to raise their hands after the takbirat al-Ihraam (the takbir to start the prayer).

The chapter quotes:

- The prophet () according a report on the authority of [al-Bara' ibn 'Azib](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33038/2720#p1) and ['Abdullah ibn Mas'ud](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33038/2721#p1)

Among the sahbah:

- 'Ali ibn abi Talib
- Abduallah ibn Mas'ud
- 'Umar
- His son 'Abdullah ibn 'Umar
- as a statement of ibn 'Abbas

Among the Tabi'yn:

- A-Sha'aby.
- Ibraheem an-Nakha'iy
- Khaythama
- Qays
- ibn abi Layla
- Al-Aswad ibn Yazid an-Nakha'iy
- 'Alqamah
- abu Ishaaq

As for the report which is an Athar on 'umar ibn al-Khattab () it says:

> 2454 - حدثنا يحيى بن آدم، عن حسن بن عياش، عن عبد الملك بن أبجر، عن الزبير بن عدي، عن إبراهيم، عن الأسود، قال: «صليت مع عمر، فلم يرفع يديه في شيء من صلاته إلا حين افتتح الصلاة» ([Source](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33038/2734))
> I prayed with Omar, and he did not raise his hands in any of his prayer except when he opened the prayer.

Let's check the narrator chain:

- Yahya ibn Adam [يحيى بن آدم](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=1647&bk_no=60&flag=1): Is declared as trustworthy by scholars, such as Yahya ibn Ma'yn, abu Dawod, abu Hatim and an-Nasa-i however he did report some manakeer (one of them even with a trustworthy chain of narrator as a-Dahhabi mentioned in his siyar a'alaam an-Nubala' سير أعلام النبلاء) His hadith can be found in both Sahihs and elsewhere.
- Hasan ibn 'Ayyash [حسن بن عياش](https://al-maktaba.org/book/31596/4404) is the brother of abu Bakr ibn 'Ayyash the qari' of 'Assim, and both were declared as trustworthy by ibn Ma'yn. His haidth appears in Sahih Muslim and other sources.
- 'Abd al-Malik ibn Abjar [عبد الملك بن أبجر](https://al-maktaba.org/book/31596/4404) is regarded as a good narrator by ibn Ma'yn, ibn Hibban quoted him among the trustworthy (in his book at-Thiqaat الثقات) and imam Muslim reported two ahadith of his narration according al-Khateeb al-Baghdadi in his Tareekh Baghdad, a simple search on [sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/search?q=%D8%B9%D8%A8%D8%AF%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%84%D9%83%20%D8%A8%D9%86%20%D8%A3%D8%A8%D8%AC%D8%B1) gave me at least 6 ahadith in Sahih Muslim.
- Az-Zubayr ibn 'Ady [الزبير بن عدي](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=1000&idfrom=0&idto=0&flag=1&bk_no=60&ayano=0&surano=0&bookhad=0) was declared trustworthy by Ahamd ibn Hanbal and al-'Ijly. He was a direct student of Ibraheem an-Nakha'iy and his hadith appears in both Sahih's. He directly narrated from Anas ibn Malik too.
- Ibraheem (an-Nakha'iy) [إبراهيم النخعي](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=663&idfrom=0&idto=0&flag=1&bk_no=60&ayano=0&surano=0&bookhad=0) Yayha ibn Ma'yn said he would accept his maraseel. He met a lot of sahabah, but didn't record any ahadith from them without intermediate. And he learnt qira'a and reported from his maternal uncle al-Aswad.
- Al-Aswad (ibn Yazeed an-Nakha'iy) [الأسود بن يزيد النخعي](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=455&idfrom=0&idto=0&flag=1&bk_no=60&ayano=0&surano=0&bookhad=0) a tabi'y who was born during the prophet's lifetime and who was a student of ibn Mas'ud's qira'a and he is regarded as a source of knowledge in al-Kufa and as trustworthy by scholars such as Ahmad ibn Hanbal, Yahya ibn Ma'yn, ibn Sa'ad and his hadith appears in the six sahih books.

So as you see the narrator chain of this Athar is of a high standard.